# Reset username for user

Tags: discussion, status-completed

So I found [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/85027) user. His needs nuking. Can a mod do that?

Comment: For future reference, you can also bring this sort of thing to our attention by posting in [chat].

Comment: @UniKitty huh, why not?

Comment: @DavidZ Because [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/t6hOQ.png). Someone got me suspended on [gaming.SE] :(

Comment: To all curious people: even though tpg edited out the reason why that account deserved nuking, evidence remains in the edit history. And ROFL, for user 85027's thought process while setting up a Physics.SE account!

Answer (score 6):

For future reference: if you see a user with a username you consider offensive, the correct procedure is probably to flag the post with a custom flag explaining it. Moderator action will probably follow quickly. As a second avenue, try [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71/the-h-bar), and if both of those are unavailable then raise the matter on meta.

Answer (score 4):

## Yes

<sub>they can,</sub>
<sup>let's wait for one to come.</sup>

---

## **o.0**

This user was destroyed.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Please say such things as comments.

Comment: o.0​​​​​​​​​​​​

Comment: New user hype things!

Comment: @Uni Comments don't allow beautiful formatting.

Comment: Want mod answer, this does not satify my needs.

Comment: @Uni ...​​​​​​​

Comment: This seems like a perfectly valid answer to me.